# angular onclick events on plain text html elements

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rxjs, angular-directive

New to angular, I have array of  responses with below structure

```
{
   type:typeid,
   title:"99695 procedure id",
   description :"procedure  99265 related to repair of system  56 with combination of 98745 procedure"
 }
```

I need to identify numbers with specific pattern and make them clickable elements[not hyperlinks, better understanding purpose I made hyperlinks here], description field from API response should be formatted like below.

**procedure  [99265](https://goto_procedure_99265) related to repair of system  [56](https://goto_system) with combination of [98745](https://goto_procedure) procedure**

Using regex I had replaced matching patterns in text with `<span style='cursor:pointer'><a>matchednumber</a></span>` so subsequently when angular component rendering 'description' field all numbers are getting highlighted as clickable elements.

**Problem**

I need to register/trigger events like mouse over or click events. How can I  bind events on above elements. I tried life cycle methods

> ngAfterViewInit on component, ngAfterContentInit on directive

but they need some 'template'  to be defined first to get element reference to bind events(correct me if I'm wrong here)

Going through lot of articles/examples but not able to get solve. Can you please suggest how can dynamically register events on 'plan html' content rendering from angular component.

Comment: Instead of replacing with text <span style='cursor:pointer'><a>matchednumber</a></span>, you could try to replace with some kind of your own component like this: <app-link value=matchednumber></app-link>. Then you can inside your app-link component bind click event.

Comment: Can you explain please, why not to bind to event in simple Angular way with (click)="onClickMethod(matchednumber)"? O imperatively with @HostBinding? As a side note, <a> element should point to link (router or external), otherwise it's a button.

Comment: @AvgustinTomsic replacement is not happening in template it self, we have a separate service to identify and replace matched text, return value of that service being used as input to angular component so if I'm trying to use some custom tag in replacement it just printing as plain text not rendering as angular tag.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis I need  component defined for that to bind but those components are not getting recognized by angular as component but instead rendering them as plaintext.

I need hyperlinked style so used <a> without link,

Comment: It depends on pattern the description field follows. If it's always the same, you can use static html template with changing values like `<span>{{descr[0]}}</span><a>{{descr[1]}}</a>`. If pattern changes, you can use structural directives like ngIf or create your own directives. Or imperatively create DOM nodes from components or templates.

Comment: Hi, I don't know how correct this solution is, but you can try adding this to your component
```@HostListener("click", ["$event"])
  onClick(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("yourClassNameAddedToSpanInRegex")) console.log(e.target);
  }```